# Ignore flag from .bashrc

Tags: unix, bash

I want to never have my day ruined by `rm -f` again, but I don't have the self-control to stop. I'd like to do something in my bashrc to have "rm" ignore the "-f" flag.

My current .bashrc skills (aliases and functions) don't seem to be able to solve this problem. If I alias "rm" or replace it with a function, I overwrite the actual "rm" and no longer can remove anything. What can I do in my .bashrc to have "rm" ignore "-f"?

Comment: You can use `command rm` to ignore any functions or aliases by the same name to access the actual, on-disk, `rm` command.

Comment: That's only half the problem, though. It's not trivial to remove `-f` from any legal invocation. You might add `-i` to the end of any options, which will override any preceding `-f`, but that swings the pendulum too far to the other end of the spectrum.

Comment: I was assuming I could access the list of flags being passed in to my function and just carefully parse out "f"s.

Comment: There isn't a one-to-one correspondance between flags and arguments; consider `rm -rfv somefile`.

Comment: Yea.. you could roll your own rm script and then alias `rm` to that script. Or name the script `rm` and make sure it loads first in your `PATH` variable. Then you can get fancy with `getopts` and just pass through whatever flags you want to the real `rm` using it's full path. It's not a simple fix and I'm certain there are more than a few gotchas going this route, but it's something.

Comment: Can't you just put it in a function called rm, check if there is a -f flag, and if not run the bin version.

Comment: The fundamental question is a common FAQ going back at least to the early '90s, and probably much longer. The TL;DR is to teach yourself to think before you type. Never looked back after I picked that up (but still learning).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets the job done. It will prevent you from using -f, but should still allow you to delete files that contain "-f" in them, as long as that file's name isn't made only of valid "rm" options. If you have a file named as such, you can rename it before you "rm" it. This was written for OSX, and as such looks for exactly the options that OSX recognizes as rm's flags.

```
function rm() {
    for arg
    do
        if [[ $arg == *"f"* ]] && [[ $arg =~ ^-[dfiPRrvW]+$ ]]
        then
            echo "rm is trying to -f!"
            return 1
        fi
    done

    command rm "$@"
}
```

**EDIT**: changed return code to 1

Comment: Ah, thanks. Got that mixed up and thought 0 was the error code.

Comment: One other concern; `-[dfiPRrvW]+` looks like an extract from an OSX or FreeBSD man page. Linux has a few more options, HP/UX has a few less...  To be portable, you should probably try to determine what options are available, or you should mention on what platform(s) you expect this function to work best.

Comment: Do you know of a programmatic way to extract a command's options, so I can make this more platform-independent?

Comment: Just the first test should be sufficient. Let the command handle other errors. After all if the the user gives `rm -r` you're saying "rm is trying to do -f" which is clearly wrong.

Comment: `rm -r` does not trigger the error case. The first test looks for an "f" in the argument and the second test checks to see whether the argument matches the format of flags. Only if both are true do I want to warn the user that -f is being used.

Comment: @dshapiro, I know of no such way. This method of testing is further complicated in Linux by rm's support for "long" options like `--verbose`, `--recursive`, `--force`, etc. You might implement separate tests with `case $(uname -s) in...` since I don't think anything but Linux uses long options, And I'd test for a match on `^-[a-z]*f` in an argument and not try to overthink this. Or don't worry about portability, and just use a function that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to warn about this approach, because You will get used to the protection - and one day you may work on a foreign machine, not Your own, where no such modifications are made, and then the trouble will likely be a lot bigger.

I might instead suggest a different approach:
I suitably solved such problems (accidental deletions) by running incremental backup over the homedirs (and some other critical areas) every 10 minutes. This works very well if you do mostly development or editor work (small to medium files), it would not work if you handle big media files or similar. I have excluded Download and Media and .cache from the backup. I am using bacula, which may be not all too easy to configure for a beginner, but there are also other tools around. It is some work to get this proper working, but over the years it spared me enough headaches that I consider it worth the effort.
The main thing that is needed to make this work is a place to store the backups. This is normally on a different machine that works as backup server, but for the issue of accidental deletion it could also be some protected filespace on the same machine. Today it probably could even be on the web (but beware security issues).

Comment: I understand your concern. My hope is to actually stop using -f. My script actually prevents any removal if -f is involved. So, every time I use -f, nothing will be removed, and I'll have to retry the command without the -f. I think this should eventually retrain me to stop using that option.